# Adding a unique/(=ascending) number to each .txt file in a folder (with Batch)

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with lots of .txt files with random names. Now I want to add a unique/ascending number to the end of each file in the folder. Example:

> File 1 named "blah blah.txt with the content "hello world"
>
> File 2 named "blah blah blah.txt with the content "hi hello world"

And after running the .bat file the files should be like:

> File 1 named "blah blah.txt with the content "hello world1" <-- number "1" added
>
> File 2 named "blah blah blah.txt with the content "hi hello world2" <-- number "2" added etc.

I wrote this line so far:

```
FOR %%a in (*.txt) do ECHO 1>> %%a
```

This adds a "1" to each .txt in the folder.
Theoretically I have to exchange the "1" with a variable

Comment: Do all of the files have only 1 line of text in them?

Comment: yes only one line of text

Answer (score 1):

If all files have only one line, and no line begins with `:`, then

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d *.txt ^|findstr /n "^"'
) do for /f "usebackq eol=: delims=" %%L in ("%%B") do (echo %%L%%A)>"%%B"
```

If dealing with multi-line files, and each line within a file is supposed to get the same number appended, then the following modification will work.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d *.txt ^|findstr /n "^"'
) do (
  (for /f "usebackq eol=: delims=" %%L in ("%%B") do echo %%L%%A)>"%%B.new"
  move /y "%%B.new" "%%B" >nul
)
```

Comment: This works well with the added `^` character. Multi-line files will have only one line in them - the last line.

Comment: @foxidrive - You are right on both counts. Thanks. I added an alternative that should now work with multi-line files.

Answer (score 0):

For the indicate scenario, with only one line per file and a value added to the end of it

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "var=0"

for /r . %%a in (*.txt) do for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("%%~fa") do ( 
    set "line=%%b"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >"%%~fa" echo(!line!!var!
    endlocal
    set /a "var+=1"
)
```

In a recursive search from the current folder and below (`/r .`), for each of the .txt files (`%%a`), for each of the lines in the file (`%%b`) echo the added variable after the readed line into the same file from it was read. In each loop the variable value is incremented by 1.

The `setlocal/endlocal` game inside the loop is intended to deal with special characters (!) inside the text in the file

Comment: how would one modify it for multiple lines?

Comment: but how does one have the numbers increase with this?

Comment: @user3314067, sorry, i missed the increase part of the question. Corrected. For the multiline question, you need to better define the behaviour for each line/file.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do (
  set /a inc+=1
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("%%~fa") do (
    >"%%~fa" echo(%%b!inc!
  )
)
```

Comment: This will corrupt lines that contain `!`. There are various ways this could be fixed.